# A nearest neighbor data structure for meshes

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, search-algorithms, nearest-neighbour

I am trying to find a lightweight data structure to find the nearest neighbor mesh (a mesh being a collection of non-unique triangles) for a given point in R3 (3D Euclidean space). I have seen nearest neighbor problems for points and triangles, but never meshes as a whole collective.

So, in essence given a point P find the nearest mesh M to the given point P from a collection of meshes (some sort of query structure so this can be done over and over again), where the nearest neighbor mesh M is defined as the shortest Euclidean distance in R3 between the point P and the nearest point on a triangle in the mesh M. I was thinking maybe some sort of generalized voronoi diagram where each cell is associated to a list of meshes, but I start thinking about concavity of meshes and intersecting meshes and the point P inside of closed meshes and the point P inside of intersecting closed meshes and even the all the previous cases with open meshes then I am lost. Is there any such known structure for this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is decomposing the mesh into convex subsets an option? I believe that's a common approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to store all of the triangles from all of the meshes in a nearest-neighbor data structure for triangles.  Then, given a point P, find the nearest triangle, check which mesh that triangle is a part of, and that will be the nearest mesh.

Comment: This is probably an optimal approach. I don't see how knowing that the triangles are organized in meshes could be exploited to speed up the search.